# Google Account and Facebook Account for Login in Google AppEngine Application (Java)

Tags: java, facebook, google-app-engine

Currently, my application only allow users to log-in using their google account. Im now in the process of allowing Facebook account to be used for the site.

Since only google account was the authentication method, i used the UserService for checking if a user is logged in:

```
    UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
    User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
```

Since I will add Facebook account, what will be the best method to check if a user is login? On either google account or facebook account?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook logins work differently to Google's and you'll need to implement Facebook's OAuth flow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/

When the user returns to your site they will have an `access_token`, you can use this to query the Facebook Graph API.

Comment: i understand that both have different implementation, my concern is how to track which is used by the user when log-in in the site. thanks @Ahmed

Comment: Consider using sessions: once the user has logged in via Facebook and the `access_token` is valid, then create a standard cookie based session for that user.

Comment: it is safe to store the access_token as cookie?

Comment: No. Use Facebook's JS SDK to keep tracks of the FB session. If you need to run tasks in the backend on behalf of the user then consider using application `access_tokens`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications/